SharePoint Online Doc Library - Uploaded document to New Doc Set, missing metadata
The fix for this might be something simple I'm overlooking.  But I have a Document Library, where the user fills out an SP default form with metadata (people pickers, dates, choice, etc.).

When they submit, a new Doc Set is created successfully.
When I navigate to the new Doc Set, and upload a file, it doesn't populate all of the columns that were initially populated a moment earlier.

Is there a way I can populate all of those columns when a new Document is uploaded?  The reason is that there a some required fields, and you can't check-in the file unless those columns are filled out - which they were initially, but not in the doc set folder.
Any help would be great.  Thank you!
